# Is there a specification for a man page's SYNOPSIS section?

Tags: syntax, manpage

I'm trying to write some specifications to be shared between a small team and getting picky about the format I put some command listings in. Is there any *formal* definition of the syntax used in the SYNOPSIS section of man pages?

From the Wikimedia Commons, here's an example of a man page with the SYNOPSIS section I'm talking about, where the command is listed with the required and optional arguments it understands.

[image: Unix manual page on the "man" command]

Comment: Read the BUGs-section of `man 7 man` carefully. You should not write sophisticated man pages anymore. Instead a sane primer should point to the more usable Texinfo/ `info` pages.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no formal definition of a manpage anywhere, not even in the POSIX standard. The `man(1)` manpage in your example is pretty typical: you write out the various ways a program can be used (often just one) with `[]` denoting optional, bold (or typewriter font with the [`mdoc`](http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=mdoc&section=7) macros) denoting literal command line input and italics denoting variables.

The manpages `man(7)` and `mdoc(7)` will explain the most important conventions. `man(7)` is for old-style Unix manpages and is still popular on Linux (see `man-pages(7)`); `mdoc(7)` comes from 4.4BSD and is popular in its derivatives. The latter maintains a stricter separation of content and presentation and can produce (IMHO) prettier PDF/HTML output

Comment: what about {} and the <> since i had found them in many man pages

Comment: There is a posix doc about that - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html

Comment: The above doc does not seem to cover `{}`.

Comment: The `{opt1 | opt2 | opt3}` syntax seems to indicate one and only one of the options must be used, but I could not find this documented.

Answer (score 16):

The utility conventions for utilities are documented in in [Chapter 12. Utility conventions of the IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html).

A newer edition of this document exists [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

Answer (score 16):

man 7 man-pages:

> briefly describes the command or function's interface. For commands,
>   this shows the syntax of the command and its arguments (including
>   options); **boldface is used for as-is text and italics are used to
>   indicate replaceable arguments. Brackets ([]) surround optional
>   arguments, vertical bars (|) separate choices, and ellipses (...) can
>   be repeated.** For functions, it shows any required data declarations
>   or #include directives, followed by the function declaration.