# Where can I find some info about a syntax in JS docs?

Tags: javascript, syntax, documentation

I have met many times a syntax like `arr.fill(value[, start = 0[, end = this.length]])` in JS docs and etc. and I have been forced to understand it myself. I mean spelling of the function's parameters.
It is not a big problem anyway, but I would want to know more about this syntax.

Comment: can you give an example of where you have seen this?

Comment: No brackets = required argument.

Comment: It's kinda pseudo code, arguments in brackets are optional, additionally, values for optional arguments are shown. Usually docs have a "Convention" chapter explaining the syntax.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I have seen it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style of documentation is based on the style used in command line tools and `man` pages, which appears to be based on [this standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) (following the links from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716047/is-there-a-specification-for-a-man-pages-synopsis-section)). That notation has been pretty standard for API and usage docs for some time.

The brackets (`[,start = 0 ...]`) denote an optional part of the syntax, although order is important. In your example, the nested brackets show that the preceding sections are required if you want to specify a later parameter.

For the MDN docs, this is combined with a `name = value` notation to show what parameters are referred to within the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.fill(value[, start = 0[, end = this.length]])
         ^---^
    required argument
              ^--------------------------------^
                      optional arguments
```

This notation specifies the order, requirement, and default values for arguments. No brackets means the argument is required. Brackets means the argument is optional. What's after the equals is the default value for the optional argument.

So given that signature, you have the following options:

```
arr.fill(value) // start = 0, end = this.length
arr.fill(value, start) // end = this.length
arr.fill(value, start, end)
```