# JavaScript and Node.js - Understanding function arguments and knowing what to provide?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I came from a Java background and I'm studying Node.js & js in general.

I'm looking at [this](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener) and [this](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) sample core functions from the Node.js library as I'm walking through a for-starters tutorial.

The documentation states what should be passed but I'm confused with the `(foo[,bar])` part and I'm having a tough time understanding the following:

what does an argument enclosed in `[]` mean?

what's up with that comma inside `(foo[,bar])` or `([foo][,bar])`?

why is it that when I try to call createServer like this, it's not giving any errors stating to pass the arguments expected?

```html
const http = require("http");
let server = http.createServer();

console.log('running');
server.listen(8080);
```

is there such a thing as optional arguments and how would I know if those are optional?

Apologies for such a basic question but answers and advice are really appreciated.

Comment: `[]` means that this argument is optional.

Comment: The syntax comes form unix manual pages (if you look up for the manual for ls or find for example the arguments will be using this syntax). The square brackets means that the argument is optional, you can give either one argument or two. The comma inside the square bracket because it would have been a syntax error if you give only one argument but end it with a comma

Comment: Yeah, I guess saying "parameters in square brackets are optional" solves all of OP's questions.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716047/is-there-a-specification-for-a-man-pages-synopsis-section

Comment: Related: [What do the brackets around the arguments mean when reading documentation for a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654192/what-do-the-brackets-around-the-arguments-mean-when-reading-documentation-for-a)